# Retrieving tweets from twitter

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I want to retrieve tweets from `twitter` and save it in `CSV` file. I use the following code but no result is showed and no errors. what is wrong?

```
import tweepy
import csv

consumer_key = 'xxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxx'
access_token = 'xxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

search = raw_input('Search :> ')
csvFile = open('result.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                            q='{}'.format(search),
                            since = "2018-07-1",
                            until = "2018-07-4",
                            lang = "ar").items():
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
    print tweet.created_at, tweet.text
csvFile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free API only returns tweets from the last [7 days](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview/standard) (1 week). You are searching for tweets older than that :/